# Switch statement is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

It gives always answer "Hello City" although i pressed 1 and 2.. what is wrong with the code? what is better to use ? if else statement or switch statement?
anyone can help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function number()
{

var number;
number=document.getElementById('m').value;

switch (number)
{
case 1:
day="Hello World";
break;

case 2:
day="Hello Asia";
break;

default :
day="Hello City";


}
document.write(day);

}


</script>

<input type="number" name="" id="m">
<input type="submit" name="Click" onclick="number()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the value explicitely to a number otherwise it will be a string, the `Switch` statements in Javascript always use strict type checking (===), thus your example will always return the default value.

```
var number= +document.getElementById('m').value;
```

Comment: it worked ...but i did not get this yet. we dont have to tell javascript it is number or string just like we do in php.javascirpt does't get the data type by its own ?

Comment: @YousafFarooq All `value` properties on DOM elements are strings. You will have to explicitly cast the value to another data type if you want to treat it as such.

Comment: @YousafFarooq i've edited my answer. there's no type coercion in the switch statements, so you have to match the type as well :)

Comment: @YousafFarooq and do you think, that  `"20" == "XX"` should be true? Because both are twenty, one in Arabic, and one in Roman numerals.

Answer (score 0):

What about parse to integer.

`var number=parseInt(document.getElementById('m').value)`

Switch testing strict quality. So there is used triple equals.